# Fallout 4 Sneak gear

Tags: fallout-4

Been trying to research this but can't find a concrete answer.

If I'm trying a sneak build, am I better using the "shadowed" versions of the combat /leather armors, or not wearing armour and instead using the 'clothes', like tuxedo etc, that benefit the relevant SPECIAL stats (such as increasing agility).

Bearing in mind that what I'm looking for here is just the most benefit to sneaking, actual damage protection isn't such a concern as I'm looking to just not get seen and thus not get hit. Not including power armor with the stealth boy add on in this.

Anybody know what is better for sneaking stats? Shadowed armor or normal clothes?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Asked this question an other forum too, had this answer which seems pretty good

"
Some outfits may have pretty good stats to start with, but later in the game you can get more of boost using whole sets of pieces like the combat armor. Outfits seem to just limit your abilities at higher levels
"